# Would a loop without delaying in Assembly crash my PC?

Tags: assembly, x86, infinite-loop, bootloader

I am trying to make a simple x86 Operating System, but I was concerned about something.

If I am making a loop in x86 Assembly (without a delaying function), would my computer crash if I were to run the compiled code on my PC?

```
loop:
    .globl kernel
    jmp loop

times 510-($-$$) db 0

dw 0xaa55
```

Comment: What makes you think it would?

Comment: It may drive up CPU time usage to 100% on one core. That can heat up your CPU, though when properly installed that should not cause damage. To avoid this problem, make a loop like this: `loop:` \ `sti` \ `hlt` \ `jmp loop`

Comment: Note that most preemptive operating systems use tight loops called [spinlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock), when the loop|wait time is expected to be very small.

Comment: What does "crash" mean? When a computer crashes, that means it's *not doing anything useful* and *not responding when you press keys or move the mouse*. That's what a crash *is*. Your bootloader doesn't do anything useful, and it doesn't respond when you press keys or move the mouse. So...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

An endless loop like this will do nothing to your PC. It won't crash and won't damage your PC. It is quite difficult to physically destroy hardware from software.

Comment: But will it crash the software?

Comment: No. It's just an endless loop, no different to `while(1){}`.

Comment: @MatthewMajfud-Wilinski: Unless you count being stuck in an infinite loop as "crashing", then no, of course not.  Just try it yourself in a normal program, or in this bootloader.  In fact an infinite loop (containing `hlt` or not), is the standard way to end a toy bootloader since there's no OS to exit back to.  Since you don't disable interrupts, you don't interfere with the BIOS's ability to notice keypresses like ctrl+alt+delete.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.

Comment: Nitpick: _will do nothing_, _won't damage your PC_: These should be changed to "should", not "will"/"will not". A properly designed PC will not have problems, but hardware failures in the cooling system can cause a modern CPU to shutdown due to overheating (old CPUs without thermal monitoring could be damaged by excessive heat). This could also drain the battery, resulting in a low power shutdown, which may or may not be able to complete cleanly.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, which is no worse than any CPU intensive code that actually _does_ something, running on a regular OS (unless the thermal monitoring is dependent on the OS, which I really hope it would not be, at least not in full).